# I am building a text-based game in react that I am converting from JS. How can I make the variables mutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is initially a JS project from free code camp, but to put it on my portfolio website, I want to make it interactive.

I have tried setting the variables to state and being passed down through props, but the variables will only but initially mutated once, and the display will not update further than that. Here is some of the code that should give an idea of the whole project.

The state for button functions, button text, and text all update and display properly, but the button functions only set the state once and continue to call on the original state.

```
//JSX file
export default function DragonRepeller() {
const [health, setHealth] = useState({ health: 100 });
const [gold, setGold] = useState({ gold: 50 });
const [text, setText] = useState({ text: 'Welcome to Dragon Repeller. You must defeat the dragon that is preventing people from leaving the town. You are in the town square. Where do you want to go? Use the buttons above.'});
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState({ button1: "Go To Store", button2: 'Go to Cave', button3: 'Fight Dragon'});
const button1Text = buttonText.button1
const button2Text = buttonText.button2
const button3Text = buttonText.button3
const [buttonFunction, setButtonFunction] = useState({button1: goStore, button2: goCave, button3: fightDragon});
const button1Function = buttonFunction.button1
const button2Function = buttonFunction.button2
const button3Function = buttonFunction.button3
// various other initializers and some objects 
const locations = [
        {
            name: "town square",
            "button text": ["Go to store", "Go to cave", "Fight dragon"],
            "button functions": [goStore, goCave, fightDragon],
            text: "You are in the town square. You see a sign that says \"Store\"."
        },
        {
            name: "store",
            "button text": ["Buy 10 health (10 gold)", "Buy weapon (30 gold)", "Go to town square"],
            "button functions": [buyHealth, buyWeapon, goTown],
            text: "You enter the store."
        },
        {/*location[2] commented out for space*/},
        {/*location[3]*/},
        {/*location[4]*/},
        {/*location[5]*/},
        {/*location[6]*/},
        {/*location[7]*/}
    ];
//location functions
    function update(location) {
        setButtonText(() => {
            return {
                button1: location['buttonText'[0]],
                button2: location['buttonText'[1]],
                button3: location['buttonText'[2]]
            }
        });
        setButtonFunction(() => {
            return {
                button1: location['button functions'][0],
                button2: location['button functions'][1],
                button3: location['button functions'][2]
            }
        });
        setText(() => {
            return { text: location.text}
        });
        };
//button functions that use the update(location) function
function goTown() { // starting location
        update(locations[0]);
    };
    function goStore() { // this is the location with the function in question
        update(locations[1]);
    };
    function goCave() {
        update(locations[2]);
    };
//buy health button function, buy weapon works the same 
function buyHealth() {
    if (gold.gold >= 10) {
       setGold((prevGold) => { return { gold: prevGold.gold - 10 }});
       setHealth((prevHealth) => { return { health: prevHealth.health + 10 }});
  } else {
       setText(() => { return { text: 'You do not have enough gold to buy health' }});
  }
 }
//the rest of the code
}
return (
<div id=game>
   <div id='stats'>
      <span className='stat'>Health: <strong><span id='healthText'>{health.health}</span></strong></span>
      <span className='stat'>Gold: <strong><span id='goldText'>{gold.gold}</span></strong></span>
   </div>
   <div id="controls">
       <button id="button1" className='gButton' onClick={button1Function}>{button1Text}</button>
       <button id="button2" className='gButton' onClick={button2Function}>{button2Text}]</button>
       <button id="button3" className='gButton' onClick={button3Function}>{button3Text}</button>
   </div>
   <div id='text'>
      {text.text}
   </div>
</div>
)
```

I feel like I am going about this the wrong way and could use some help.

I have tried rewriting the code multiple times with varying ways of setting state. Every time I run the code, the text will keep updating can following along with what I have it set to change to, but the other variables only mutate once and then they revert to either the initial state or the first way it changed.

I have tried plain JS instead of JSX and that has run into more issues with the functions not executing.

I have also been scouring stack overflow to find anything that might relate to this but I have not found any solution that works which makes me feel like I am missing a key point here.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you have shared here, but it seems to be an incomplete example. For example, `buyHealth` is not used and I don't see where anything is passed down as props to any children components. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: More code has been added to create a minimal reproducible example, thank you for the help. As for props, I have tried making the buttons and stats have their values passed down as props and have them change at the parent level but i kept running into the same issues. This is the original copy of the code that I had made that was most functional.

Comment: You are storing callback functions in your state, probably don't want to do that. With so many similarly named variables it's kind of difficult to read your code and understand what you want it to do.

Comment: I guess the main question I am looking for is if my gold state is 50, and I click the button with the buy function that reduces gold by 10, i can only reduce the state by 10, it wont go any further so the state never fully updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You have closed over the `gold` state in the `buyHealth` callback function which is closed over in the `locations` object which is closed over in the `buttonFunction` state depending on where you travel in your game.

In other words, it is a stale Javascript [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), the value of `gold.gold` doesn't get updated to a value from the outer scope when the state actually changes until you update the `buttonFunction` to a different state and back to re-enclose the current `gold` state value in the stack of callbacks.

## Solution

The solution I'd suggest here would be to create a lookup map of the callbacks you'd like to assign to your UI's buttons 1, 2, and 3, and invoke these at run time with the current values of the closure of the Function component. The lookup should be by a location that is stored in state, not the callbacks stored in state.

Example:

```
const LOCATION = {
  CAVE: "CAVE",
  STORE: "STORE",
  TOWN: "TOWN",
};

export default function DragonRepeller() {
  const [health, setHealth] = useState(100);
  const [gold, setGold] = useState(50);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Welcome to Dragon Repeller. You must defeat the dragon that is preventing people from leaving the town. You are in the town square. Where do you want to go? Use the buttons above.');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("town");

  function goTown() {
    setLocation(LOCATION.TOWN);
    setText(locations[LOCATION.TOWN].text);
  };

  function goStore() {
    setLocation(LOCATION.STORE);
    setText(locations[LOCATION.STORE].text);
  };

  function goCave() {
    setLocation(LOCATION.CAVE);
    setText(locations[LOCATION.CVE].text);
  };

  // buy health button function, buy weapon works the same 
  function buyHealth() {
    if (gold >= 10) {
      setGold(gold => gold - 10);
      setHealth(health => health + 10);
    } else {
      setText('You do not have enough gold to buy health');
    }
  }

  const locations = {
    [LOCATION.CAVE]: {
      ....
    },
    [LOCATION.TOWN]: {
      name: "town square",
      buttons: [
        { text: "Go to store", handler: goStore },
        { text: "Go to cave", handler: goCave },
        { text: "Fight dragon", handler: fightDragon }
      ],
      text: 'You are in the town square. You see a sign that says "Store".'
    },
    [LOCATION.STORE]: {
      name: "store",
      buttons: [
        { text: "Buy 10 health (10 gold)", handler: buyHealth },
        { text: "Buy weapon (30 gold)", handler: buyWeapon },
        { text: "Go to town square", handler: goTown }
      ],
      text: "You enter the store."
    },
  };

  ...

  return (
    <div id=game>
      <div id='stats'>
        <span className='stat'>
          Health: <strong><span id='healthText'>
            {health}
          </span></strong>
        </span>
        <span className='stat'>
          Gold: <strong><span id='goldText'>
            {gold}
          </span></strong>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="controls">
        {locations[location].buttons.map((button, i) => (
          <button
            key={button.text}
            id={`button${i + 1}`}
            className='gButton'
            onClick={button.handler}
          >
            {button.text}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div id='text'>
        {text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, will perform the overhaul and ill be back soon! Thanks Drew.

Comment: IT WORKS! I have been working on this for so long. Thank you. Now i have to iron out all the bugs but I think it all goes back to creating the lookups and not modifying the state directly. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
setGold((prevGold) => { return: { gold: prevGold.gold - 10 }});
```

syntax error at return :

change to: for both.

```
setGold((prevGold) => { return { gold: prevGold.gold - 10 }});
```

Comment: My bad.. I definitely did not have that in the source code, thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, there is actually a specific "vote to close" reason for issues that are "not reproducible or caused by typos" like this. Answering posts with these issues is frowned upon because they are of no significant long-term value to future readers. You have enough rep and have been around for 8 years so I'm certain this is something you should already be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

When you use arrow function, if the function body contains only a return statement, you can remove the `return` keyword.
If the return value is an object, you can wrap it using `(` and `)`.

These are examples.

```
const multiple = (x) => { return 2*x }
const object = (value) => { return { key: value } }
```

These are the same as the following:

```
const multiple = (x) => 2 * x
cosnt object = (value) = ({key: value})
```

So, please use following to avoid potential errors.

```
setGold((prevGold) => { return { gold: prevGold.gold - 10 }});
```

```
setGold((prevGold) => ({ gold: prevGold.gold - 10 }));
```

Comment: The function syntax isn't what the post/question is about.